# Is there any way to save local variables in animation nodes?

Tags: scripting, physics, animation-nodes

I'm simulating a physical system and I need to store local variables for solving the differential equations of the movement and I was wondering if there is a way to store variables from one frame to another (for example the velocity). Also, is possible to do this in a Phyton script? A invoke subprogram node in the animation nodes that calls a script execute it every frame, so I don't see the way of storing there variables from frame to frame....
I kind of solved this problem creating a cube and storing in the variables that I need in its location (with a transformation output node), but I feel that there should be a more elegant way of doing this...
Thank you!

Comment: Hi. It is easily possible in Animation Nodes + Extra Nodes. I have added Simulation Nodes, these nodes allow you to do exactly what you have mentioned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKhLLys63KA

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!